# Using a WRT54G V8 as a repeater and print server?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, dd-wrt, wrt54g

I currently have an old WRT54G V8 setup with my printer (HP Laserjet 400M 401DN) to broadcast it's own wireless network (no internet, just printer). The printer works wirelessly with this setup but I have to switch my wireless networks when I want to print. It's annoying.

I would like to use it as a repeater for my established wireless network. I'm planning on loading it up with DD-WRT. My question is, would I then be able to plug my printer (HP Laserjet 400M 401DN) to it with an Ethernet cable and use it wirelessly.

Does anybody know of an easier way to do this (possibly without using DD-WRT)?

It doesn't appear that the standard firmware allows for repeating and I'm nervous about bricking the router. Also, I'm on a Mac running 10.8.4. I know some command line stuff and other computer bits and bobs under the hood, but don't expect too much.

Comment: You are interested in using DD-WRT... what have you learned about installing DD-WRT on your router from their site http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index ?  Has your research on their site informed you that you can indeed do what you want with that model router?  Has your research informed you that you can turn that model router into a repeater with DD-WRT?  As it stands, with the firmware it comes with, you **cannot** use it as a repeater, so if DD-WRT will add that functionality, you will have to use it (as opposed to using it as a repeater as it is).